# How to preserve RGB color while saving png using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, color-profile

I've written a python program that combines three png images into a single image. I'm using PIL to open, resize, combine, and save the resulting image. All the functionality is there but the resulting image has a completely diferently color profile from the original.

I have tried several options:
1. I've attempted to create the new Image as "RGBA"
  **Result:** Image no longer displayed by TKinter GUI
2. Attempted to copy the color profile from the original image then using that profile when saving the final image:
   **Code:** `profile = image.info.get("icc_profile", "")` then I use the resulting variable when saving the file using the argument   `icc_profile = profile`
   **Result:** No change

**Minimal Reproducible Code**

```py
from PIL import Image as pImage
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

newImage = pImage.new('RGB', (976, 976))
background = pImage.open("Gameboy_Background.png")
screen_shot = pImage.open("screenshot.png")
cover_art = pImage.open("[coverart.png][1]")
newImage.paste(background)

w, h = screen_shot.size
newW = 875
newH = int(newW * h / w)
screen_shot = screen_shot.resize((newW, newH), pImage.ANTIALIAS)
newImage.paste(screen_shot, (50, 155))

w, h = cover_art.size
newW = 175
newH = int(newW * h / w)
cover_art = cover_art.resize((newW, newH), pImage.ANTIALIAS)
newImage.paste(cover_art, (100, 205))

file2Save = asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes={("PNG files", "*.png")})
newImage.save(file2Save + ".png", "PNG")
```

***PNG IMAGES USED***
    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypr02.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj1wo.png
    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iauQ.png
    [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2voFC.png

[Resulting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypr02.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate on your `profile = image.info.get("icc_profile", "")` code? Where does `image` come from, and how does it relate to `pImage` and `bg`? What do you do with `profile` after you create it?

Comment: I don't understand. You say you have written code to combine 3 PNG images, yet it only opens one PNG image? Also, you haven't provided your 3 images, instead you have just provided a screengrab of one of them, which might be totally different - e.g. it may be a PNG-format grab of a BMP-format image so if doesn't help much. Thank you.

Comment: @Kevin I’ve edited the post. I tried using the resulting profile as a modifier when saving the image.

Comment: I'm still not clear what `image` is, though. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Kevin I have provided a reproducible example. I have also removed the confusing images. However the previous resulting image was a screenshot of two PNG files opened side by side on the screen. Image B was the original PNG used to generate Image A.

Comment: Nope I can’t see the output image produced by your code and saved to disk (according to your code0. Downvote. And close vote for ‘unclear what you are asking’.

Comment: @barny Added the image once more. I’d lbe grateful for your input on how to improving on the question. I want it to be useful for future users with a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `profile = image.info.get("icc_profile", "")` then I use the resulting variable when saving the file using the argument `icc_profile = profile`

That sounds like the right approach to me, actually. `image` is the screenshot image, right? That's the one whose profile you want to copy.

```
from PIL import Image as pImage
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

newImage = pImage.new('RGB', (976, 976))
background = pImage.open("Gameboy_Background.png")
screen_shot = pImage.open("screenshot.png")
cover_art = pImage.open("coverart.png")
newImage.paste(background)

profile = screen_shot.info.get("icc_profile", "")

w, h = screen_shot.size
newW = 875
newH = int(newW * h / w)
screen_shot = screen_shot.resize((newW, newH), pImage.ANTIALIAS)
newImage.paste(screen_shot, (50, 155))

w, h = cover_art.size
newW = 175
newH = int(newW * h / w)
cover_art = cover_art.resize((newW, newH), pImage.ANTIALIAS)
newImage.paste(cover_art, (100, 205))

file2Save = "output"
newImage.save(file2Save + ".png", "PNG", icc_profile=profile)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Upvote because in the presence of vagueness and ambiguity in the question, and the absence of a result image in the question, you produced one. Well done!

Comment: That worked! At least in the minimal reproducible code. I had done the same procedure on the full program, but maybe I was copying the wrong profile. Also I had copied the code for getting the profile. It used single quotes ( ' ' ) as in ('icc_profile', ' '). I "corrected" it when I copied the code to stackOverflow.

Comment: This was the solution. Apparently I was selecting the wrong image to get the profile from. I was selecting the color profile of the background since it loads statically at the beginning. If you have a suggestion to make the **Question** and **Title** more specific please let know.

Answer (score 0):

I think so there is a problem when you open and read the image.Try this use tkinkter gui to open and read files and then use numpy to convert into array. A code like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
//get ur extension as png file
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
images = Image.open(file_path)
image_data=np.asarray(image)
image_data = cv2.cvtColor(image_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

U have ur image in rgb mode in image_data variable save it or use it for further processing

Comment: Bhavin Thakar can you check the new minimal reproducible code I've added to the question and clarify where your modification would go. Thank you.